# Cannot recieve XML structur with angular 7 injected http class

Tags: xml, angular, http, xml-parsing, http-headers

i have some issues with a more or less trivial problem about getting and reading an recieved xml-Object that i got in this way:

```
const params = new HttpParams().set('val1', val); // setting parameters 4 get request
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Accept': 'application/xml',
  'Response-Type': 'text'
});
this.http.get(Url , { headers, params}).subscribe( data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

When i append headers in the above way i got an 404 error in Chrome (similar in FF). The server wasn't reached because of CORS restrictions: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

If i now append no further headers like simply

```
const params = new HttpParams().set('val1', val); // setting parameters 4 get request
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
this.http.get(Url , { headers, params}).subscribe( data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

i reviece the error msg:

"Http failure during parsing for http://etc".

I'd like to be able to read and process the incoming xml responsedata. I double and triplechecked the cors settings on the serverapplication (asp.net 4.6) on IIS 8.5 and appended the headers and they should be fine but i don't understand really what has happend here (CORS rules where bypassed anyways by the browser).

Thx alot.

Comment: I have the same problem,

Comment: I get this message when I add a handleError => Http failure during parsing for "URL"

Comment: I am using angular 8 by the way